# jenkins failed to generate build automatically using bitbucket

Tags: jenkins

Here i am using jenkins and installed 'bitbucket' plugin and 'bitbucket pull request builder' plugin.

`In my system i use git-gui client,i clone the bitbucket,all the commit and push operations happened successfully.`

`In jenkins i give the bitbucket central repository url in source code management in git repositories,i try the build now it is working but,the problem is whenever i push the data from my local client to bitbucket it doesn't generate the build automatically, i give the details in 'bitbucket pull request handler' also but it doesn't generate automatically`.

`can any one please help to me.`

Answer (score 0):

Have you setup a CRON Job for your actiity ?

To launch build automaticly, you should link your job to to your bitbucket repository **AND** setup rules that launch your job.

I personnaly do like CRON tasks that checks whenever updates are available on your git repo.
A command like that will chekc every 5 minutes :

```
*/5 * * * *
```

For more info about CRON jobs, please refer to that link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Here is a screenshot of one of my conf ... sorry, it is in french 
[image]

Comment: even if i tried the above it doesn't generate the build automatically whenever bitbucket get pull request.